# Publishing android library as maven jar

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jar, publishing

Gradle/maven newbie here. I have created a library that is currently published to bintray/jcenter as an AAR, to be used with gradle in Android Studio projects.
However, since my library doesn't really have any hard Android dependencies, and may be used in any Java SE environment, I would like to publish it also as a normal jar. Since I am not very familiar with the non-android java development community I am not sure if this means I should publish it to Maven central, or would developers typically be fine fetching my library from bintray, given that the library is actually hosted in a maven repo on bintray? 
Should I simply extend my artifacts to include the jar (alongside with the aar, the javadoc and the source jar), or should I typically publish the jar separately, say to Maven central?

Getting the bintray/jcenter stuff up and running was no picnic, I found a few guides on how to do it, but none was really complete, but finally I have it working. I am however having a surprisingly difficult time finding a similar easy guide for maven publishing.

My gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 1
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
}

group = <my library name>
version = <my version>

dependencies {
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    options.overview = 'src/main/overview.html'
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = <my library name>
        websiteUrl = <my site url>
        vcsUrl = <my git url>
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
    }
}
```

The `com.github.dcendents.android-maven` plugin offers an `install` task that produces the AAR, Source Jar and Javadoc Jar. I have defined my own bintray task that publishes the library to bintray. What would be the easiest way to create a task for publishing my library also as a standard jar to maven? Can I use `com.github.dcendents.android-maven` for this as well, or do I need a separate plugin?

Comment: If your project doesn't use anything at all from the Android SDK and is pure java, and will always be that way, I'd consider redoing the whole thing to just be a java jar library.  It'll be easier to build and maintain that way.

Comment: My library has integration points in the form of a config class that can be implemented to tie it together with any host environment, but it does implement a default config for android. So it does use some Android classes, but guarded by reflection.

Comment: Yeah, that's a tough thing to resolve.  I experimented with something like this a long time ago.  I think I made a java library project depend on an android library project in order to grab a hold of the android project's knowledge of the location of android.jar to compile against.  Best of luck if you want to try that -- I think it's possible.

Comment: Hmm, but the act of getting the jar shouldn't be difficult? When I run install, a classes.jar is produced as an intermedidate under build\intermediates\bundles\release while compiling the AAR. This doesn't have any R.java etc, so as long as I guard all android dependencies with reflection, this should work? So, what would be the normal gradle-y task of producing this jar as a result rather than an intermediate? Of course, it may be a better idea to have the non-android java code as a base library, and the android addition kept separate, in code only used when producing the AAR target.

Comment: Also, my question regarding where and how to publish the jar to bintray and/or maven central is still valid.

Comment: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html

Comment: Yes, I don't have an opinion on where it should be published.  You could publish it in your own repo as well and give people the URL to it.

Comment: If you just want to grab the classes.jar out of the build folder, I don't see why that wouldn't work.  Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: It *works* but what I'm looking for is the correct, Gradle way of doing it, I.e. with a task that produces a sanely named jar and uploads it to maven repo.